# Pattern Matching in a Haskell Function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have many methods that have boilerplate code in their definition, look at the example above.

```
replace:: Term -> Term -> Formula -> Formula
replace x y (Not f)            = Not $ replace x y f
replace x y (And f g)          = And (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
replace x y (Or f g)           = Or (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
replace x y (Biimp f g)        = Biimp (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
replace x y (Imp f g)          = Imp (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
replace x y (Forall z f)       = Forall z (replace x y f)
replace x y (Exists z f)       = Exists z (replace x y f)
replace x y (Pred idx ts)      = Pred idx (replace_ x y ts)
```

As you can see, the definitions for `replace` function follows a pattern. I want to have the same behavior of the function, simplifying his definition, probably using some pattern matching, maybe with a wildcard `_` or `X` over the arguments, something like:

```
replace x y (X f g)          = X (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
```

For avoiding the following definitions:

```
replace x y (And f g)          = And (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
replace x y (Or f g)           = Or (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
replace x y (Biimp f g)        = Biimp (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
replace x y (Imp f g)          = Imp (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
```

Is there some way? Forget about the purpose of the function, it could be whatever.

Comment: Maybe `DeriveFunctor` or make an explicit instance of it? Then the above might end up as `replace x y = fmap (\z -> if x == z then y else x)`. Of course, that means that `Formula` will have kind `* -> *`, but that sounds reasonable. `Formula Bool` would be a boolean formula.

Comment: You could make `Formula` an instance of [`Compos`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Compos.html), would that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have many constructors that should be treated in a uniform way, you should make your data type reflect that.

```
data BinOp      = BinAnd | BinOr | BinBiimp | BinImp
data Quantifier = QForall | QExists
data Formula    = Not Formula
                | Binary BinOp Formula Formula -- key change here
                | Quantified Quantifier Formula
                | Pred Index [Formula]
```

Now the pattern match for all binary operators is much easier:

```
replace x y (Binary op f g) = Binary op (replace x y f) (replace x y g)
```

To preserve existing code, you can turn on `PatternSynonyms` and define the old versions of `And`, `Or`, and so on back into existence:

```
pattern And x y = Binary BinAnd x y
pattern Forall f = Quantified QForall f
```

Comment: I like that but the bad news are with this I must rewrote every single method.

Comment: @jonaprieto I have added a sentence to address this concern.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you are looking for but you could do the following. The idea is that you can consider a formula to be abstracted over another type (usually a `Term` in your case). Then, you can define what it means to map over a formula. I tried to replicate your data definitions, although I have some problems with `Formula` - namely that all the constructors seem to require another `Formula`...

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Formula a
  = Not (Formula a)
  | And (Formula a) (Formula a)
  | Or (Formula a) (Formula a)
  | Biimp (Formula a) (Formula a)
  | Imp (Formula a) (Formula a)
  | Forall a (Formula a)
  | Exists a (Formula a)
  | Pred a (Formula a)
  deriving (Functor)

data Term = Term String {- However you define it, doesn't matter -} deriving (Eq)

replace :: (Functor f, Eq a) => a -> a -> f a -> f a
replace x y = fmap (\z -> if x == z then y else z)
```

The interesting thing to note is that now the `replace` function can be applied to anything that is a functor - it even serves as `replace` for a list!

```
replace 3 9 [1..6] = [1,2,9,4,5,6]
```

**EDIT** As an afterthought, if you are implementing a substitution style replace where terms in formulas can be shadowed (the usual scoping rules), you will probably end up doing something like this:

```
replace' :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Formula a -> Formula a
replace' x y f@(Forall z _) | x == z = f
replace' x y f@(Exists z _) | x == z = f
replace' x y f@(Pred z _)   | x == z = f
replace' x y formula = fmap (replace' x y) formula
```

Which isn't as cute, but also isn't as straightforward pf a problem.

Comment: I don't think that last one is going to work. `fmap` is going to expect something of type `a -> a`, but you're handing it something of type `Formula a -> Formula a`. (But the rest of the advice here is solid.)

Answer (score 2):

[Data.Functor.Foldable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) abstracts the pattern of recursive data structures:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data FormulaF t
  = Not t
  | And t t
  | Or t t
  | Biimp t t
  | Imp t t
  | Forall A t
  | Exists A t
  | Pred B C
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

type Formula = Fix FormulaF

replace :: Term -> Term -> Formula -> Formula
replace x y = cata $ \case ->
  Pred idx ts -> Pred idx (replace_ x y ts)
  f -> f
```

By the way, beware of `replace x y (Forall x (f x)) = Forall x (f y)`: [Substitution is the process of replacing all **free** occurences of a variable in an expression with an expression.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Substitution)

Comment: I wonder why was this downvoted? Is there any issue with this approach? (Beyond variable capturing and substituting non free occurrences, which are common with other answers so far)